# What does "constantly wearing masks" mean in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Over the centuries various writers and thinkers, looking at humans from an outside perspective, have been struck by the theatrical quality of social life. The most famous quote expressing this comes from Shakespeare: "All the world's a stage, / And all the men and women merely players; / They have their exits and their entrances, / And one man in his time plays many parts.“ If the theater and actors were traditionally represented by the image of masks, writers such as Shakespeare are implying that all of us are **constantly wearing masks**. Some people are better actors than others. Evil types such as Iago in the play Othello are able to conceal their hostile intentions behind a friendly smile. Others are able to act with more confidence and bravado—they often become leaders. People with excellent acting skills can better navigate our complex social environments and get ahead.

Comment: The whole passage seems designed to explain precisely what that phrase means so you need to tell us exactly what your problem is by editing.

Answer (score 2):

"Constantly" here means much what it usually would - that is, "constantly wearing masks" means "wearing masks all the time".

The rest of the text indicates that the "masks" are metaphorical.  Masks hide faces, the text is talking about people hiding what they're thinking and trying to give other people a false impression of what they're thinking.  (This metaphorical use of "wearing a mask" is quite common in English.)  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, wearing a mask in the sense that one is hiding one's identity, or pretending to be someone or something else.

People are always wearing masks; the mask of politeness, the mask of manners.

The expression "putting on a good show" comes to mind. Think of politicians.

Answer (score 0):

It means that we always, all the time, play a pretend persona we want to be seen as (by others and even by ourselves), rather than openly acting out our natural selves.